# How can I AppleScript Terminal.app to copy the current text on the screen?

Tags: terminal, applescript

I see in the AppleScript dictionary that the current screen's worth of text and the history buffer are available as properties.

How would I AppleScript that to copy the contents of the currently selected Terminal.app tab to the paste buffer?

Could I do it on the command line?

What about the whole history log?

Comment: are you looking for command history or everything in the Terminal buffer?

Comment: Everything in the terminal buffer.  Command history is easy, just 'history'.  Sometimes there's an exception or a log I want to grab, but it went off the screen or select-all is a pain.  I want to make a cmd line tool that does it and maybe sends it to a new gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy the contents of the currently selected Terminal.app from the command-line:

```
osascript <<END
  tell application "Terminal"
    tell front window
      set the clipboard to contents of selected tab as text
    end
  end
END
```

For the history:

```
osascript <<END
  tell application "Terminal"
    tell front window
      set the clipboard to history of selected tab as text
    end
  end
END
```